# Random word sequence or grammatical structure?

Tags: littérature

I know not to get too phased by literary language, but as a learner of French I would like to make sure that when some examples of the language seem odd to me it is because they are literary and not because there is something going on grammatically that I don't realise.

I came upon this passage in the story 'Le Personnage' (1994) by the Canadian writer Gloria Escomel:

Le moindre mot me fait trébucher, le moindre adjectif me fait peur, tandis qu'alors, dans notre innocence romanesque nous nous soûlions de ces clichés [...]: vers de quatre sous, paroles de chansons, **midinettes fleur bleue panache** et bohème folklorique...

and I wonder about the words in bold. I assume we are looking a noun followed by an invariable adjectival phrase followed by another noun. But is this just a completely literary, random sequence of words or is there some kind of grammatical structure present that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

***Midinette fleur bleue*** and ***bohème folklorique*** are unsurprising collocations and perhaps examples of *clichés* mentioned before but you are right to be puzzled by the word ***panache*** between them. The author is possibly giving an example of a words/phrases combination that is more or less left to the reader interpretation.

While it is possible to understand ***panache*** as some kind of qualifier for ***fleur bleue***, I see no clear grammatical structure here.